# Creating Charts in apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

how do I show in a pie chart the percentage of the total value. eg lets say I have total sick leave which is 30 days and I take 15 days, how in a pie I show 15/30

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, to get a percentage value, you'd divide those two values and multiply them by 100 (and, possibly, round the result to 0, 1 or 2 decimals).

That would be - in your example - 50%, right?

```
SQL> select round(15 / 30 * 100, 2) from dual;

ROUND(15/30*100,2)
------------------
                50

SQL>
```

Chart query expects 3 columns to be specified, e.g.

```
select null as link,
       what as label,
       number_of_days as value
from some_table
where some_condition
```

If you could provide test case so that we'd see what you really have, we'd be able to suggest something more.

Comment: well the database is on the companies domain so access to it will not be possible, but I have a employee_info table that has the amount of sick and vacation days they took.. But I don't have the total number of days they are allocated eg(14days sick , 21 days vacation).. so what I basically want from a report form is charts (pie , bar etc) of the sum of the sick and vacation days  with the total allocated days. So if I take 3 days the pie chart should show 3/14